# Combine double foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have one product table and one order table and I want to combine these data to draw bar chart. If I run orders foreach loop products will not showing and if I run products then orders will not show. How to combine these?

```
$query_product = "SELECT *,count(products.id) as no_products FROM products group by MONTH(products.added_on) , YEAR(products.added_on)";

$query_order = "SELECT *,count(orders.id) as no_orders FROM orders group by MONTH(orders.added_on) , YEAR(orders.added_on)  order by YEAR(orders.added_on) asc, MONTH(orders.added_on) asc";

$result_order = mysqli_query($con, $query_order);
$result_product = mysqli_query($con, $query_product);
$chart_data = '';

$product_data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_product)) {
    $product_data[] = $row;
}

$order_data = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_order)) {
    $order_data[] = $row;
}

foreach ($order_data as $key => $val) {
    $date = $val['added_on'];

    $month_year = date('F, Y', strtotime($date));

    $chart_data .= "{ year:'" . $month_year . "', income:" . '5' . ", products:" . '' . ", orders:" . $val['no_orders'] . "}, ";
}

//I want to gain my data like this below string.

 //$chart_data .= "{ year:'".$month_year."', income:".'5'.", products:".$val['no_products'].", orders:".$val['no_orders']."}, ";

}
```

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "How to combine these"? How should the result look like? What else have you tried to resolve the problem? And why do you build json strings on your own instead of using an array and `json_encode`?

Comment: Hi, I want to show my data like
$chart_data .= "{ year:'".$month_year."', income:".'5'.", products:".$val['no_products'].", orders:".$val['no_orders']."}, ";
if I used double foreach loop then I will not get the result as I needed, I want If I add product then data will show only products and If I place order then data will show me  orders and product for each month I hope you understand.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, once more: why not use `json_encode`?

Comment: I'm beginner, I don't have idea about json_encode, I'm trying to learn, that's why I used array and loops

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this - use an associative array to store your data since you are grouping it by month/year

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_product)) {
    $product_data[date("m-Y", strtotime($row['added_on']))] = $row;
}


while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_order)) {
    $order_data[date("m-Y", strtotime($row['added_on']))] = $row;
}
```

Now you can reference the array:

```
foreach ($order_data as $key => $val) {
    $date = $val['added_on'];

    $month_year = date('F, Y', strtotime($date));
    $keyFind = date("m-Y", strtotime($date));

    $chart_data[]= array(
        "year" => $month_year, 
        "income" => '5', 
        "products" => $product_data[$keyFind]['no_products'],
        "orders" => $val['no_orders']
     );
   }

   // NOW make it json
   $chart_data = json_encode($chart_dta);
```